# default(Nullable(type)) vs default(type)

Tags: c#, default, nullable

In C#, is there a difference between `default(Nullable<long>)` (or `default(long?)`) and `default(long)` ?

`Long` is just an example, it can be any other `struct` type.

Comment: Ye...you're right. I'm not at a compiler though...so I thought to ask. Will test these in the future rather than ask...question can be deleted if moderator wants.

Comment: Check out http://ideone.com/ for an online compiler

Comment: Still, I think the community can agree that it is useful to have even the most simple questions answered so that instead of 30, it takes no longer than 5 seconds to resolve a query (at least for the rest of us).

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ is also a nice online compiler.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Well yes.  The default value of a nullable or other reference type is `null` while the default value for a `long` or other value type is `0` (and any other members set to their defaults).

In this case:

```
default(Nullable<long>) == null
default(long?) == null

default(long) == 0L
```